# How to change Javascript Font Color in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

I would like Visual Studio 2022 font colors for javascript files to look like the font colors in Visual Studio Code. This is an incredibly dificult question to search google for.

I would like this
[(Visual Studio 2022)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rerjI.png)
to look like THIS
[(Visual Studio Code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE9v2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Theme converter for VS](https://github.com/microsoft/theme-converter-for-vs) tool

Information about VS 2022 themes here: [Introducing Collection of New Visual Studio Themes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/custom-themes/)

[How to: Change fonts, colors, and themes in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-fonts-and-colors-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)